# symmetric systems of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have a polynomial $p(x_1,...,x_N)$ in $N$ complex variables, and I wish to solve $p(x_{\pi(1)},...,x_{\pi(N)})=0$ for all permutations $\pi \in S_N$.  Clearly this is overdetermined for generic $p$, but suppose $p$ is symmetric under exchange of all but one variable.  Then this gives $N$ distinct equations, and so generically one expects a discrete set of solutions.  Are there any general techniques for solving such a system of equations?  I'm most interested in simply counting the number of solutions (up to permutations).

Comment: Hm, you can solve the system using Gröbner bases. If it is symmetric, you might be able to do some tricks, to speed up the computation. If you can post a concrete example of $p$, I might be able to elaborate.

I have looked a bit on common zeros of certain specializations of Schur polynomials (related: http://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/Articles/Around-Multivariate-Schmidt-Spitzer-Theorem.pdf ), and this type of things appear.